# LG G series: wrong resource provided at runtime

Tags: android, android-resources, lg

I'm getting very weird crashes on LG-H830 (6.0.1) and LGE VS985 4G (6.0):

```
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-anydpi-v24/$hexagon_line_age__0.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f070009
```

The issue, that it can't inflate a vector drawable with a gradient on pre-Nougat devices, is known. That's why these resources are in `drawable-anydpi-v24`.

The question, why these devices are trying to load `v24` resources, leaves me clueless. A ROM bug?

Comment: You will need to provide some snippets of code (preferably around the area where this error is being identified) to help identify issues with greater accuracy. Otherwise people will just be making guesses about the issue you are facing

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue? Have the exact same problem in my app.

Comment: @geiger Did you find a solution?

Comment: @eightx2 no, unfortunately

Comment: Same, on LG K10 LTE, Android 6. Interesting...